# Interpreter design in Python

Tags: python, compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter, pypy

I am new to Python, and I want to make a small interpretor/compiler with it. just a hobby project initially. I would like to know how good is it in comparison to c/c++ to accomplish such a job? it has highly efficient string processing library built in it. So i guess it would be initially easy to start off (see links bellow) but to build a language will it do well when the complexity really becomes high?

## some resources

http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/37/a-simple-interpreter-from-scratch-in-python-part-1

### This one is really simple but good to start :

http://www.jroller.com/languages/entry/python_writing_a_compiler_and

### Another place to visit :

http://morepypy.blogspot.in/2011/04/tutorial-writing-interpreter-with-pypy.html

http://morepypy.blogspot.in/2011/04/tutorial-part-2-adding-jit.html

the lst one uses pypy though. and I am not familiar with it. I am using cpython

Comment: What is the real question? Python is VERY good for prototyping, but your mileage may vary depending on how proficient you are in C++.

Comment: You've answered your own question. It is fine for the task.

Comment: As I mentioned. I am sure it is fine for a start-off or as you call it "Prototyping". But my question is mainly on how is it for a full featured language? Sorry if i framed the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how complex your language is. I wouldn't use Python for a C++ compiler, but I found it very convenient for writing code generators that parsed code in one language, specifically the data definition subset of SQL, to generate code in another language.

Consider using a parser generator, rather than do it all by hand. I find [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) very convenient.

Comment: +1 for parser generators. Python's great for string job but structured languages are a step harder and a formal approach really helps

Answer (score 2):

> to build a language will it do well when the complexity really becomes high?

as the complexity increases, you will be grateful that you chose to implement this in Python instead of in C/C++. The only thing I suggest is to use parsing libraries, like PyParsing, to reduce the amount of work you need to do (unless you also want to learn how to implement parser as well).

Comment: While ply takes a more conventional approach for the parser generation (the lex/yacc toolchain in python) the PyParsing looks very promising also. I would rather try to make a simple grammar implementation in both and do some benchmarking. I think it would be good. What you suggest 

BTW, thanks for the suggestions.